# Selecting correct entities and fields in Rules

Tags: 7, rules, ubercart, entities

I am using the Rules interface to set up some rules about a booking site I am building. (using AGReservations+Ubercart in Drupal 7)

I have a field called Duration which is part of an entity called Reservation, which is itself is part of Ubercart's Order entity. I am having trouble getting my conditions to fire on the value of Duration, because there are many different entities and I am not sure if fields bundled with Entities are entities themselves, or how to pull the values out so that I can run my conditions and have the desired action.

Is there any module or tutorial to simplify this process? Something that makes it easier to know what kinds of data you have rather than plain trial and error?

Answer (score 0):

**Rules Module**

Rules has a built-in debugger that can be fairly useful to see what was passed to your rule.  It can be found and enabled at admin/config/workflow/rules/settings

---

**Devel Module**

The [Devel module](http://drupal.org/project/devel) is another tool that is very valuable when debugging Rules. If you are working with custom code there are two functions in particular that will save you tons of time.

[dd](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dd/7)() and [dpm](http://api.drupal.org/api/devel/devel.module/function/dpm/7)().

dd() will write debugging data to file.  Generally to /tmp/drupal_debug.txt on *nix based systems.

dpm() will display debugging data to screen, but may be a little less useful when debugging rules as redirects at times can cause issues while viewing.

**Usage Examples**

```
dpm($form);
dd($form_state);
```

Rules is an incredible module, but debugging can be a pain for sure.  I would be happy to clarify if the above doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is helping me get on the right track. Still confused about how I can get that Duration field in my node from the Order entity. I Hopefully there is a module to help me out.